# Is this a secure way to authenticate with API?

Tags: php, database, api, authentication

I want to create a game for mobile and web but I'm a little bit lost in how I can authenticate and communicate with one central codebase.

Let's say:

- I have a main website: `https://www.example.com`
- I have multiple game servers: `https://server1.example.com` / ...
- I have a mobile app

Both should always communicate with the same codebase so that I don't have to write my code twice. My idea was to do all actions related to the database with an api: `https://www.api.example.com`.

For example:

- The login and register form for server 1 on `https://www.example.com` should request `https://www.api.example.com/s1`.
- The app does the same.

And when I do some actions, for example: establish a new city:

- the game server should give this to the api: `https://api.example.com/s1/establish`
- the app does the same.

My question is: **is this the right and secure way to do?** I see some websites doing the same, but some websites don't request an api. Hope you can give me some info I can get started with.

Comment: the API structure looks sensible yes - you're making the app and the website share the same methods to do the same things. But security is an a separate issue really. Your method structure is ok, but that has no impact on security. You need to decide how your app and website will authenticate to the server. You already seem to have https, which is good. But then you need to decide on an authentication scheme, there are many possiblities - I suggest you research them and decide what might suit you.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use JWT I think.